# K8S Jobs are being created although backoffLimit

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-cronjob

EKS 1.24

A VERY strange situation is occurring with jobs.

Although I set `backoffLimit: 0` and `restartPolicy: never` sometimes after a pod is failed, a new one is created.

According to the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-backoff-failure-policy), a new pod shouldn't be created with my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `backoffLimit: "0"`

0 might be interpreted as some kind of null value. It helped in my case.